# Samsung Galaxy S2 or Samsung Nexus i9250 for testing?

Tags: styles, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, mali

Since I want to develop for ICS I would like to buy a 4.0.3 smartphone for testing my applications. I don't want to release apps I only tested with emulators (I guess who's ever developed j2me apps knows why...).

I have to choose between the S2 and the Nexus i9250.
S2 seems to be more powerful and it is very popular but it is not the original ICS 4.0.3 style. Nexus i9250 OS is pure android ICS, also it is a bit cheaper.

Do android applications look different on the S2? Im talking about widgets like TimePickers and so on.

Sincerly,
Wolfen

**EDIT:**

The main question is:
Will TouchWiz affect my applications in any way?

Comment: Please consider that [Stack Overflow doesn't provide product or service recommendations](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/128562/143302)

Comment: I'm asking this question in term of software development. I don't ask for a simple recomendation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, they will.

Touchwiz and HTC Sense change the look of widgets such as buttons, date and time pickers etc. Starting from Ice Cream Sandwich, you can [force](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2012/01/holo-everywhere.html) the device to use the stock Android Holo theme look. But remember that Galaxy S2 comes with Gingerbread unless you update it.

Comment: Thank you. That's what I wanted to know :)

Answer (score 0):

In terms of Graphics, the Mali-400 GPU of the S-II beats the PowerVR SGX 540 of the Nexus...

But if you're testing certain features like NFC, you're likely to go with the Nexus.

Why not wait for the S-III? It's got the features of both.

Comment: Unfortunately my budget doesn't allow to buy a S3 :( . The main question is if TouchWiz will affect my Applications view, if it won't I will go with the S2